# Getter / Setter for List

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0

i have one method followed:

```
public List<Car> getCart(){
 //do something
}
```

and in JSF Page i user this method for display Data in h:dataTable

and in view (JSF Page) i have one inputText in h:dataTable, example in h:dataTable i have 2 column are Cart Name and Quantity, and column Quantity is inputText for user edit Quantity of item.
My Problem is how can i set value for List dataType? because i have formular for update cart follow:

```
Quantity of Cart Update = (Item In stock + old Quantity of each item) - new Quantity of each item
```

in upon formula i can get item instock , but i wonder between old Quantity of each item and new Quantity of each item because if i get Quantity of each item it will new value. But now i just only get value of old Quantity of each item, because i don't know how can setter for List

Everybody can have any ideas for this problem and my formula?

Thank you

===============================================

Edit

my List Cart method in backin bean

```
public List<Cart> getUserCart(){
        int userid = getMemberLoginController().getUser().getUserid().intValue();
        return cartDAO.getUSerCart(userid);
    }
```

cartDAO is Session Bean Stateless it do getResultList where userid = :userid.

and update method

```
 public void updateCart(){
        List<Cart> cartQuantity = getUserCart();
        int i = 0 ;
        for(Cart cartQuantityOnHand : cartQuantity){
            i = cartQuantityOnHand.getCartQuantity();
            int a =  i + cartQuantityOnHand.getItem().getInstock();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
     }
```

how can i get old Quantity on hand of List and new Quantity on hand of List?

Answer (score 1):

The list doesn't need a setter. JSF will only call its getter and then call the setter on each of the list's items.

Your problem sounds like as if you're loading the list inside the getter everytime instead of in bean's constructor or postconstruct. If you're getting the list by its getter in the bean's action method, then the original list with all submitted values will be overridden with the new one from the DB.

So, you should NOT design it as:

```
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Item.list", Item.class).getResultList();
}

public String submit() {
    for (Item item : getItems()) {
        em.persist(item);
    }
    return "outcome";
}
```

But you should rather design it as:

```
private List<Item> items;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    items = em.createNamedQuery("Item.list", Item.class).getResultList();
}

public List<Item> getItems() { 
    return items;
}

public String submit() {
    for (Item item : items) {
        em.persist(item);
    }
    return "outcome";
}
```

Comment: Hi BalusC,i'm not put getResultList in postconstruct or constructor , i have edited my question, you can check it. Thank you

Comment: Thank you BalusC! but how can i still old Quantity in other list? do i need ask new question for this issue? because Quantity in stock equal current in stock + old quantity - new quantity

Comment: I don't quite understand you. Normally, when you bind a model property to an input component and edit the value, then JSF will already update the model value. Also, in your updated code you're still reloading the list from database in the getter and hereby overridding the submitted values.

Comment: I know! Thank you! but do you have any solution for update Shopping Cart? my solution i think it impossible to do because old value can not get!

Comment: i can get oldQuantity with use loop for getUserCart()